# Not able to exec into AKS pod

Tags: kubectl, azure-aks

I'm trying to exec into one of the pods of my AKS instance using the following command: kubectl exec -n hermes --stdin --tty hermes-deployment-ddb88855b-dzgvt -- /bin/sh. I'm using just the regular CMD from Windows, but I'm getting the following error:

> ```
> error: v1.Pod: ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta: readObjectFieldAsBytes: expect : after object field, parsing 3193 ...:{},"k:{\"... at {"kind":"Pod","apiVersion":"v1","metadata"
> ```

The error is quite long with some meta data and environment variables I believe. I can't share the meta data due to corporate restrictions.  I'm logged into Azure using az login, and also have the correct context in my kubeconfig.

Does anyone know what this error exactly entails?

Comment: consider adding your "**regular CMD**" to the question for completeness.

Comment: also, add the `metadata` of the pod you are attempting to `exec`

Comment: I've added the CMD. I can't share the metadata due to corporate restrictions.

Comment: try updating your `kubectl.exe` to the latest version. If you believe that you are already using the latest version, kindly post the op of the `kubectl version`.